# Change SharePoint 2013 web part search query using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, powershell, search-results

I need to edit the query of a Search Results web part on multiple pages of the same site collection (with no subsites).  With the following code, I've been able to change the web part's title, but I can't find any properties on the web part related to the search query.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

#Site on which web parts need to be changed
$siteURL = "http://example.com"
$pageURL = "/Pages/sample-page.aspx"
$Site = get-SPSite $siteURL

#load required assemblies to work with client context
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.SharePoint.Client”)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime”)

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$page = $context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($pageURL)
$webPartManager = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Webparts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
#$context.Load($page)
$context.Load($webPartManager.WebParts)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$webpartDefinition = $webPartManager.WebParts[0]
$webpart = $webpartDefinition.WebPart
$webpart.title = "Changed Through PowerShell"
#$page.CheckIn()

$webpartDefinition.SaveWebPartChanges()

$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

How can I add to or change this code to replaced the selected web part's search query with my own?